# Cronómetro en Android

Tags: java, android, hilos

estoy intentando hacer un cronómetro en Android. El cronómetro solamente tiene que marcar los segundos y las décimas, es decir, 00:00. El cronómetro me funciona pero he notado que va algo más lento, es como si se retrasase. No se si se debe a que al pintar el resultado en u TextView tarda más y cada vez es mayor la diferencia entre un cronómetro normal y el mío.
A continuación os pongo mi código a ver si sabéis qué puedo estar haciendo mal. Seguramente sea una tontería pero llevo todo el día ya intentándolo. De antemano, muchas gracias.

```
public class Tiempo extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {

private Thread hilo;
private int estado = 0; //Estado = 0 es que el reloj está a 0. 1 que está en funcionamiento y 2 que se ha parado.
private TextView decimas, segundos;
private Button boton;
private int numDecimales = 0;
private int numSegundos = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tiempo);

    decimas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewCentesimas);
    segundos = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewSegundos);

    boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPush);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(estado == 0) {

                estado = 1;
                Log.d("tiempo", "estado = "+ estado);
                iniciarCronometro();

            }else if(estado == 1) {

                estado = 2;
                Log.d("tiempo", "estado = " + estado);
                detenerCronometro();

            }else if(estado == 2) {

                estado = 0;
                numDecimales = 0;
                Log.d("tiempo", "estado = " + estado);
                numDecimales = 0;
                numSegundos = 0;
                decimas.setText("00");
                segundos.setText("00");

            }

        }
    });

}

private void iniciarCronometro() {

    hilo = new Thread(this);
    hilo.start();

}

private void detenerCronometro() {

    hilo = null;

}

@Override
public void run() {

        try {

            while(estado == 1) {

                Log.d("nuevo", "Contador = " + numDecimales);
                numDecimales++;

                Thread.sleep(10);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(numDecimales > 99) {

                            numSegundos++;
                            Log.d("nuevo", "numero segundos = " + numSegundos);
                            segundos.setText("" + numSegundos);
                            numDecimales = 0;
                            decimas.setText("" + numDecimales);

                        }else if(numDecimales < 10 ) {

                            decimas.setText("0"+numDecimales);

                        }else {

                            decimas.setText("" + numDecimales);

                        }

                        if(numSegundos < 10) {

                            segundos.setText("0" + numSegundos);

                        }

                    }
                });

            }


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread.sleep(10);
```

Estás haciendo iteraciones con un `sleep` de 10 milisegundos, y contando que cada iteración tarda **exactamente** 10 ms.

No.

Puntos a tener en cuenta:

- La ejecución de la lógica del bucle (aparte del `sleep`) tarda tiempo.
- Android no es un sistema de tiempo real. En la máquina, el SO puede parar tu proceso un momento (especialmente cuando está haciendo un `sleep`!) para ejecutar otra cosa. Es tan rápido que normalmente no lo notas, pero está ahí.
- Tu `Thread.sleep` **no tiene porque acabar en 10 milisegundos**. De [la documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#sleep(long))

  > Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, **subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers**

Así que tu bucle tarda más de 10ms y se van acumulando errores.

La solución es no "contar" `sleep`s para saber cuánto tiempo llevas; lo que tienes que hacer es almacenar la hora inicial y, cada vez que tengas que actualizar la pantalla, calcular el tiempo transcurrido restando la hora en ese momento con la inicial.